# Accessing Currency Fields

Tags: multi-currency

I am using multiple currencies, and when I have a currency field that is not my company currency, then the value in my company currency is displayed in brackets.
Unfortunately this seems to be useless for me now because I cannot use the converted value in calculations. For example, I have one currency field in EUR and the other in GBP. Salesforce translates the EUR into GBP and displays it in bracket, but doesn't make the GBP value available to the user? That doesn't make any sense to me at all!
Is there a way to surface the GBP value?
Thanks.

Comment: when you say calculations - do you mean in formula fields or in apex?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of CurrencyType object and conversionrates to do math and ultimately your result. "https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_currencytype.htm".

Hope this helps!

Thanks
Pradeep

Comment: `DatedConversionRate` when using dated exchange rates; if OP wants to use formula fields, then more problematic